# Android Studio Custom Sound base on notification FCM on topic

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have to topic on FCM and it working fine.. the problem is how do i set
***custom sound*** notification base on **topic notification**? for example

```
Topic A = hello.mp3
Topic B = merra.mp3
```

Sample code

```
   private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String link) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FullscreenActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("LINK", link);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        if (FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic2"))
            customSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

        else if (FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic1")
        customSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/sound.mp3");
        )
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_dishroomlogo)
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(customSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the custom sound from assets for each notification but I'm giving example with default RingtoneManager

Send the topic name as field in notification body as data then

```
  data  = remoteMessage.getData();
  topic = data.getString(“topicName”);




Uri customSoundUri;

  if(topic.equalIgnoreCase("topic1"))
     customSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

  else if(topic.equalIgnoreCase("topic2")
     customSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setSmallIcon(new MyUtils().getNotificationIcon())
            .setContentTitle(messageBody)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orange))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: how do i declare symbol topic? in this part `if(topic.eq` cannot resolve symbol topic

Comment: How are you sending the data to topic from there only you need to send a topic : <your_topic_name>

Comment: Please check edited answer but you should send topic name to FCM server while sending notice

Comment: i have update the code on topic but still no idea where to put symbol end  )  `Error:(76, 76) error: ')' expected` at else if ( statement